# Unexpected key assets ((String)) under font - Mobile app error in flutter and dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new to Mobile development and I'm using Dart and Flutter to build mobile applications, both android and ios apps. The problem is I can't start my application and I keep getting an error related to the `pubspec.yaml` file.

When I comment the `fonts:` section, The app runs properly. But I need to load the fonts, so that is not solving my problem.

This is my `pubspec.yaml`

```dart
name: simple_app
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Oxygen
      fonts:
        - assets: assets/fonts/Oxygen-Regular.ttf
        - assets: assets/fonts/Oxygen-Light.ttf
        - assets: assets/fonts/Oxygen-Bold.ttf

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Bellow is the error I keep getting in the console.

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Unexpected key assets ((String)) under font.
Unexpected key assets ((String)) under font.
Unexpected key assets ((String)) under font.
C:\Users\user\Documents\mobile_app\flutter\simple_app\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1
```

Comment: asset, not assets. Please check  https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: omg thank you so much @AlekseyPotapov, that was my problem too and it was driving me nuts trying to figure out what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 8):

*fonts: 
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf*

Check there is a difference between asset and assets. kindly check and update it.

Answer (score 3):

please see my working example

```
  fonts:
    - family: icomoon
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/IcoMoon.ttf

    - family: Qwigley
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Qwigley-Regular.ttf

    - family: Dosis
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/dosis/Dosis-Regular.otf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/dosis/Dosis-Medium.otf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/dosis/Dosis-SemiBold.otf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/dosis/Dosis-Bold.otf
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/dosis/Dosis-ExtraBold.otf
          weight: 900
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: custom_fonts
description: An example of how to use custom fonts with Flutter

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: DUBAI
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/DUBAI-BOLD.TTF
        - asset: assets/fonts/DUBAI-LIGHT.TTF
        - asset: assets/fonts/DUBAI-MEDIUM.TTF
        - asset: assets/fonts/DUBAI-REGULAR.TTF
    - family: Dima
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/DimaPlatinum.ttf

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/azmoon.db
    - assets/qi1.png
```

and maybe you like to have a look on `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Fonts',
      // Set Raleway as the default app font.
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // The AppBar uses the app-default Raleway font.
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Custom Fonts')),
      body: Center(
        // This Text widget uses the RobotoMono font.
        child: Text(
          'Roboto Mono sample',
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

see the full tutorial on https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts.

and in case you faced the "Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml" issue see  [Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432187/error-unable-to-locate-asset-entry-in-pubspec-yaml-assets-fonts-lato-regular). 
:)